What was Schopenhauer's take on different schools of Buddhism?
It's been a while since I read Schopenhauer's masterpiece 'The World as Will and Idea', where he discussed Indian religions a lot.
I have recenlty studied the history of Buddhism somewhat in depth and became aware of the dozens of schools (theravada, mahayana, zen etc etc.), and I would like to know what Schopenhauer thought about them.
Which ones did he think were better / worse, and why?

I would be surprised if he knew much. The era is 1800; just the beginnings of the availability of oriental texts in  Christendom. But I'm no historiographer; so maybe off. But I strongly suspect he had a couple of indic texts and he drew his inferences from that. Just for reference, Kant was a few decades earlier and as best as we know was completely unfamiliar with the world of oriental philosophy
